# Combine disks/directories in a virtual volume

Tags: linux

Say I have 4 disks, they are mounted on `/home/disk[1-4]`. The file tree looks like this:

```
disk1:
    file1
    dir1:
        file2

disk2:
    dir1:
        file3

disk3:
    file4
    dir2:
        file5

disk4:
    file6
```

Is there a solution to create a virtual device or directory that combine all of this in something like this?

```
CombinedVolume:
    file1
    file4
    file6
    dir1:
        file2
        file3
    dir2:
        file5
```

Edit: As I would not be confident in my disks, it's better if a file is not split in multiple parts written in different disks. Say I lose `disk2`, the file tree will look like

```
CombinedVolume:
    file1
    file4
    file6
    dir1:
        file2
    dir2:
        file5
```

`file3` is gone but there is no alteration to other files.

Comment: That would result in undefined behavior quite quickly: What happens if `file1` exist on both disk1 and disk2?

Comment: You could use [overlayfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) for such, but don't expect too much or any magic from it.

Comment: @Sven In this case, all filenames will be unique but I think you may choose a disk that will prevail in this case.

Comment: @Thomas Looks quite interesting

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like [Hierarchical Storage Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_storage_management). The technique, creating a virtual file-system of multiple disks in a single filesystem using policies to determine what gets written where, is not much in vogue these days. The one system I know of that still does this at the file-system level is Microsoft Storage Spaces.

For Linux I don't know of anything that does this out of the box. [zfs](/questions/tagged/zfs) or [btrfs](/questions/tagged/btrfs) may be able to do this, but it would *definitely* not take an existing set of disks; if its possible with those it would be with subvolumes and disk-pools.

Comment: With Microsoft Storage Spaces, will a file be split on small parts written on different disks?

Comment: @o2640110 Took a bit to dig out, but looks like Storage Spaces is a block-level split, not a file-level one. Like ZFS and BTRFS, this is a solution that is aimed more at providing SSD or NVMe caches in front of slower storage.